# No puedo subir mi app a la consola del playstore

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

He intentado subir mi última versión de mi app, pero me sale un error en el playstore

Esto es después de haber actualizado compileSdkVersion a Android-P y traer dependencias de Android support 28.0.0-alpha1

Me sale esto exactamente en el playstore

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El oradle del proyecto es el siguiente

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"                
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "miproyecto"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 22
        versionName "1.1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex-instrumentation:2.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk25:0.10.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sqlite:0.10.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:0.10.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-cardview-v7:0.10.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-coroutines:0.10.3'
    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.2.3'
    implementation 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.6.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.pchmn:MaterialChipsInput:1.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.ethanhua:skeleton:1.1.0'
    implementation 'io.supercharge:shimmerlayout:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Puede que se deba a las dependencias que están en alpha? Hay alguna forma de pueda subirlo con ese oradle o similar, pero que no afecte tanto ya que estoy usando el diseño que trae la versión 28.

Comment: Es actualización o es una aplicación nueva?

Comment: Es una actualización que quise darle a mi aplicación con el nuevo diseño de Material Design que ofrece el Android.support v28, pero creo que eso no me deja subir al playstore por estar en alpha aun.

Answer (score 0):

Existen 2 razones por las cuales no puedas agregar una actualización de una aplicación en Google Play Store:

> - El .APK es firmado con una keystore diferente con la que se firmo la actual aplicación publicada.
> - El paquete (package name) de la aplicación o `applicationId`  sea diferente al que tiene la actual aplicación.

Noto un detalle importante, en tu archivo `build.gradle` tienes definido el `applicationId "miproyecto"`

**el  `applicationId` debe ser el paquete de tu aplicación.** Corrigelo y crea nuevamente el .apk

Comment: Hola!. Si lo firmé con la misma keystore y con el mismo ApplicationId solo que lo quité para postearlo. El problema es que el mismo playstore rechaza mi APK.

Comment: el paquete de tu aplicación es : "miproyecto" ? , agrega tu AndroidManifest.xml por favor.

Comment: Mi paquete es "pe.softhy.smiledu" y es con el que generé el apk. El problema creo que debe ser con las dependencias que están el alpha. Debería regresar a la 27? o el problema del APK es otro?

Comment: entonces en tu build.gradle debe ser applicationId "pe.softhy.smiledu" de otra forma considerará que estas intentando agregar el .apk de otra aplicación. @SebastianPeredoMurga